# Reusing one ALB in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm in the process of migration multiple microservices into ECS with Fargate. These services are set up so that traffic is routed to them based on path pattern. To accomplish this, I think I can have one single ALB, with one HTTPS Listener, and multiple Listener Rules (one per service). Each microservice is in it's own repo (this is a work project), and our desired state is to have the repo-specific Cloudformation data stay it it's own repo.

My approach was to do the following:

Infrastructure repo: ALB, HTTPS Listener, Listener Roles

each microservice: Service, Task, TargetGroup, Logs, Task Scaling, etc.

I'm hitting a wall here, in that without making a listener for each target group, my target groups don't seem to be registering my ECS tasks, nor does my ALB seem to be registering with the ECS service. 
I know little about Custom Resources, is that something I would have to do in order to accomplish this? It seems like I cannot get this working without an additional piece.

For a visual idea of what i'm hoping to accomplish:
https://www.lucidchart.com/publicSegments/view/a914fb18-fc46-4f9b-87d9-6d270afe9933/image.png

Answer (score 1):

We do exactly as you have described without any custom resources.

Our infra is organized in 2+n templates roughly as follows:

- `LoadBalancer.template` creates

  - `LoadBalancer`
  - `LoadBalancerHttpListener`
  - `LoadBalancerHttpsListener`
  - `LoadBalancerSecurityGroup`
- `ServicesCluster.template` creates

  - `ServiceCluster`
  - `ServiceClusterAutoScalingGroup`
  - `ServiceClusterCPUReservationHighAlert`/`ServiceClusterCPUReservationLowAlert`
  - `ServiceClusterCPUReservationScaleDownPolicy`/`ServiceClusterCPUReservationScaleUpPolicy`
  - `ServiceClusterInstanceProfile`
  - `ServiceClusterLaunchConfiguration`
  - `ServiceClusterLogGroup`
  - `ServiceClusterSecurityGroup`
  - `ServiceClusterSecurityGroupIngressForItself`
  - `ServiceDiscoveryNamespace`
- Per-microservice`SomeMicroservice.template` creates:

  - `SomeMicroserviceHttpListenerRule`/`SomeMicroserviceHttpsListenerRule` - connected to ALB listener with `path-pattern`, forwarding to `SomeMicroserviceTargetGroup`
  - `SomeMicroserviceTargetGroup`
  - `SomeMicroservice` (ECS Service)
  - `SomeMicroserviceTask`

Here's a piece of template for your reference. I have tried to pseudonymize it, hope it's still valid:

```
Resources:
  SomeMicroserviceTask:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    Properties:
      Family: !Sub 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-${Component}-task'
      ExecutionRoleArn: !ImportValue
        'Fn::Sub': 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-roles-ClusterInstanceRole'
      Memory: 256
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Sub 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-${Component}-task'
          Essential: 'true'
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 80
              Protocol: tcp
          Image: !Sub '${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/some-microservice:1.0.0
          Cpu: 256
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !ImportValue
                'Fn::Sub': 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-service-cluster-LogGroup'
              awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
              awslogs-stream-prefix: !Sub 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-${Component}-task'
  SomeMicroserviceService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-${Component}-service'
      Cluster: !ImportValue
        'Fn::Sub': 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-service-cluster'
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 200
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
      DesiredCount: 1
      TaskDefinition: !Ref SomeMicroserviceTask
      LoadBalancers:
      - TargetGroupArn: !Ref SomeMicroserviceTargetGroup
        ContainerPort: 80
        ContainerName: !Sub 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-${Component}-task'
  SomeMicroserviceTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-${Component}-tg'
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: instance
      VpcId: !ImportValue
        'Fn::Sub': 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-VpcId'
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: '/some-microservice/actuator/health'
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
  SomeMicroserviceHttpListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Priority: 1
      ListenerArn: !ImportValue
        'Fn::Sub': 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-load-balancer-http-listener-Arn'
      Actions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref SomeMicroserviceTargetGroup
      Conditions:
        - Field: 'path-pattern'
          PathPatternConfig:
            Values:
              - '/some-microservice/*'
  SomeMicroserviceHttpsListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    DependsOn:
      - SomeMicroserviceTargetGroup
    Properties:
      Priority: 1
      ListenerArn: !ImportValue
        'Fn::Sub': 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-load-balancer-https-listener-Arn'
      Actions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref SomeMicroserviceTargetGroup
      Conditions:
        - Field: 'path-pattern'
          PathPatternConfig:
            Values:
              - '/some-microservice/*'
```

`EnvType`, `EnvId` and `Component` are three parameters we always set in out templates. `EnvType` and `EnvId` are the same for the whole environment (ex. `dev` + `000`). `Component` is template specific, set as a constant (ex. `some-microservice`).

There are a few caveats:

- ALB does not cut the prefix of the `path-pattern` when forwarding to your microservice. So the request will be `/some-microservice/some-endpoint` and not just `/some-endpoint`.
- Make sure your microservice provides a health check endpoint specified in `HealthCheckPath`. In the example above, the microservice has to implement `/some-microservice/actuator/health` health check endpoint.

I also had problems with services/tasks not working with ALB for these two reasons.

Once my microservice was simply serving `/some-endpoint`, not `/some-microservice/some-endpoint` and I was getting `404`.

Then I've set a global prefix in the microservice and it stopped registering with ALB at all. After checking target groups I've found out that they do not have healthy targets. Apparently, I've forgotten to update the health check endpoint from `/actuator/health` to `/some-microservice/actuator/health`.

If there are problems I normally check the following:

- ECS Service is OK and have running tasks
- There's a target group with healthy targets
- Load balancer has HTTP/HTTPS listeners
- Listeners have registered rules with corresponding path patterns and forwarding to target groups
- Security group configs are OK (SG for cluster accepts traffic from the load balancer SG)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct you want to use same ALB for all listeners which points to their own target group.

This is possible directly using CloudFormation without using the custom resources.I have attached snippet of the template for reference

```
"PublicLoadBalancer": {
    "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
    "Properties": {
        "Scheme": "internet-facing",
        "LoadBalancerAttributes": [
            {
                "Key": "idle_timeout.timeout_seconds",
                "Value": "30"
            }
        ],
        "Subnets": [
            {
                "Ref": "Subnet"
            },
            {
                "Ref": "Subnet2"
            }
        ],
        "SecurityGroups": [
            {
                "Ref": "ELBSecurityGroup"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"InitialTargetGroupPublic": {
    "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 5,
        "HealthCheckPath": "/login",
        "HealthCheckProtocol": "HTTP",
        "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 3,
        "HealthyThresholdCount": 2,
        "Name": {
            "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                    {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                    },
                    "tg-1"
                ]
            ]
        },
        "Port": 80,
        "Protocol": "HTTP",
        "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 2,
        "VpcId": {
            "Ref": "VPC"
        }
    }
},
"PublicLoadBalancerListener": {
    "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
    "DependsOn": [
        "PublicLoadBalancer"
    ],
    "Properties": {
        "DefaultActions": [
            {
                "TargetGroupArn": {
                    "Ref": "InitialTargetGroupPublic"
                },
                "Type": "forward"
            }
        ],
        "LoadBalancerArn": {
            "Ref": "PublicLoadBalancer"
        },
        "Port": 80,
        "Protocol": "HTTP"
    }
},
"InitialTargetGroupPublic1": {
    "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 5,
        "HealthCheckPath": "/login",
        "HealthCheckProtocol": "HTTP",
        "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 3,
        "HealthyThresholdCount": 2,
        "Name": {
            "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                    {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                    },
                    "tg-2"
                ]
            ]
        },
        "Port": 50000,
        "Protocol": "HTTP",
        "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 2,
        "VpcId": {
            "Ref": "VPC"
        }
    }
},
"PublicLoadBalancerListener1": {
    "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
    "DependsOn": [
        "PublicLoadBalancer"
    ],
    "Properties": {
        "DefaultActions": [
            {
                "TargetGroupArn": {
                    "Ref": "InitialTargetGroupPublic1"
                },
                "Type": "forward"
            }
        ],
        "LoadBalancerArn": {
            "Ref": "PublicLoadBalancer"
        },
        "Port": 50000,
        "Protocol": "HTTP"
    }
},
```